# Angular - Testing async function with multiple http request

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have this login function and I would like to test it. But I get an error "Async callback was not invoked within 5000ms"

```js
public async Login(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const body = { email, password };
    await this.getCSRFToken().toPromise();
    return this.http
      .post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'login', body)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => {
          this.user = data;
          return this.user;
        })
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
```

My test:

```
it('should login', (done) => {
    const service: AuthenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    const http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    let userResponse;

    service.Login('email', 'password').then((response) => {
      userResponse = response;
    });

    http.expectOne((req) => {
      return req.method === 'POST'
        && req.url === '/frontend/login';
    }).flush({user_type: 'Test'});
    expect(userResponse).toEqual({user_type: 'Test'});

  });
```

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it could be for two reasons:

1. You forget to add the `done()` function at the end.

   ```
   it('should login', (done) => {
     const service: AuthenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
     const http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
     let userResponse;

     service.Login('email', 'password').then((response) => {
       userResponse = response;
     });

     http.expectOne((req) => {
       return req.method === 'POST'
       && req.url === '/frontend/login';
     }).flush({user_type: 'Test'});
     expect(userResponse).toEqual({user_type: 'Test'});
     done(); // missed done function 
   });
   ```
2. You need to increase the default timeout `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`. `

   It can be set globally, outside of any given describe.

   ```
   jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
   ```

Comment: I´ve tried to set the timeout higher and set the done function call to different positions but it doesn't matter. It seems that the HTTP call will never be reached.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to put `done()` function but to another place. Read more about async tests here: https://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support